# Can someone explain the logic diagram for the Boolean expression NOT A OR B AND C

Tags: logic

An IB question requests:
Construct the logic diagram for the Boolean expression NOT A OR B AND C.

The answer 
[image]

looks to me like not A or (B and C), whereas what I expected only gets partial credit. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3):

The question is assuming that the operators precedence goes $NOT \rightarrow AND \rightarrow OR$, which is pretty standard for boolean logic.

Hence the proper parathensization would be $\text{((NOT A) OR (B AND C))}$, which correspods to the correct diagram, whereas the partial credits corresponds to $\text{(((NOT A) OR B) AND C)}$, which would just be a left to right evaluation of the operators.